# Display the n terms of even natural numbers(between 1 and 100) and their sum

Tags: c#, console

This is a C# console application that displays the n terms of even natural numbers between (1 and 100) and their sum

Is this good? Or is it bug riddled ?

```
int numberOfEvenNumbers;
int currentNumber;
currentNumber = 0;
int counter;
counter = 1;
int sum;
sum = 0;

Console.Write("How many even numbers :");

numberOfEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (counter <= 100)
{


    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        sum += counter;
        currentNumber++;
    }

    if (currentNumber == numberOfEvenNumbers)
    {
        break;
    }

    counter++;
}


Console.Write("Sum : ");
Console.WriteLine(sum);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This code looks incomplete. Could you copy/paste the entire method?

Comment: @t3chb0t - did the post get magic-edited to include the method in the 5 minute grace period? It looks complete to me, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numberOfEvenNumbers;

// can be inlined in a for-loop
// int currentNumber = 0;
// int counter = 1;

// int sum;
// sum = 0;
int sum = 0;

Console.Write("How many even numbers :");    
numberOfEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// while (counter <= 100)
for (int counter = 1, currentNumber = 0 ; counter <= 100 && currentNumber <= numberOfEvenNumbers ; counter += 2, currentNumber++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(counter);
    sum += counter;
}


Console.Write("Sum : ");
Console.WriteLine(sum);

Console.ReadLine();
```

`for-loop` explanation:

> - `int counter = 1, currentNumber = 0`: declare and initialize your values only in the for-loop
> - `counter <= 100 && currentNumber <= numberOfEvenNumbers`: keep looping while you don't reach the 100+ values, and while you don't reach the **n**th value
> - `counter += 2, currentNumber++`: as you only want even numbers, you can increment by 2 instead of 1, and then you always count a new number (`currentNumber++`)

Answer (score 2):

It is neither good nor bad. It does the job: it shows a list of even numbers up to a limit lesser than or equal to 100. But the design or architecture of the program is ugly, even for a small program like this.

---

Previous it was common to declare all variables at the top of the scope (function or other bracketed section) (and some languages require that), but now in C# it is considered standard to declare the variable when they are used the first time.

---

> `numberOfEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

This is quick and dirty and will crash the program if the user enters a non numeric string.

So you'll have to check the input and react to an invalid such:

```
  int numberCount = 0;
  string prompt = "How many even numbers [Enter a number lesser than or equal to 50]: ";
  string errorMessage = "";
  do
  {
    Console.Write($"{errorMessage}{prompt}");
    errorMessage = "Invalid input. ";
  }
  while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberCount) || numberCount <= 1 || numberCount > 50);
```

Here I validate (`> 1 and < 100`) the input in the UI which is preferable to do compared to validating while running the algorithm.

---

The header of the question says

> numbers between 1 and 100

(excluding 100) but you iterate potentially up to and including 100:

> `while (counter <= 100) { ... }`

so what do you really mean?

---

> ```
> if (counter % 2 == 0)
> {
> ```

Even numbers can be found by checking if a number is divisible by 2 as you do, but the sequence of even numbers from 2 and upwards can be found like this:

```
  for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i += 2)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
```

in this way you are almost done with one variable (`i`) and a limit, you just need a `sum` to sum up with:

```
// The 6 first even numbers:
int numberCount = 6 * 2;
int sum = 0;    

for (int i = 2; i <= numberCount; i += 2)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
  sum += i;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

---

So all in all it ends up like this:

```
static void EvenNumberCount()
{
  int numberCount = 0;
  string prompt = "How many even numbers [Enter a number lesser than 50]: ";
  string errorMessage = "";
  do
  {
    Console.Write($"{errorMessage}{prompt}");
    errorMessage = "Invalid input. ";
  }
  while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberCount) || numberCount <= 1 || numberCount > 50);

  numberCount *= 2;
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 2; i <= numberCount; i += 2)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    sum += i;
  }

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
}
```

But here I do too much in the same method:

The program has 3 steps:

1. User input
2. The algorithm
3. Display of result

This calls for 3 separate methods or functions:

1. limit = GetCountOfNumbers();
2. result = EnumerateAndEvenNumbers(limit);
3. ShowResult(result)

Which could result in something like:

```
static int GetCountOfNumbers()
{
  int numberCount = 0;
  string prompt = "How many even numbers [Enter a number lesser than or equal to 50]: ";
  string errorMessage = "";
  do
  {
    Console.Write($"{errorMessage}{prompt}");
    errorMessage = "Invalid input. ";
  }
  while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberCount) || numberCount <= 1 || numberCount > 50);

  return numberCount;
}

static (int Sum, IEnumerable<int> EvenNumbers) EnumerateAndSumEvenNumbers(int numberCount)
{
  int sum = 0;
  List<int> evenNumbers = new List<int>();
  numberCount *= 2;

  for (int i = 2; i <= numberCount; i += 2)
  {
    evenNumbers.Add(i);
    sum += i;
  }

  return (sum, evenNumbers);
}

static void ShowResult(int limit, int sum, IEnumerable<int> evenNumbers)
{
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine($"The first {limit} even numbers are: ");
  foreach (int number in evenNumbers)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(number);
  }

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
}

static void TestNumberCount()
{
  int numberCount = GetCountOfNumbers();
  (int Sum, IEnumerable<int> EvenNumbers) = EnumerateAndSumEvenNumbers(numberCount);
  ShowResult(numberCount, Sum, EvenNumbers);
}
```

---

By the way: The sum of any number `n` of even numbers from 2 and upwards can be found as: `sum = n * (n + 1)`. This could simplify the above "algorithm" a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This can almost be a "one-liner" using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
Console.Write("How many even numbers :");

int numberOfEvenNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(counter => counter % 2 == 0).Take(numberOfEvenNumbers).ToArray();

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

Console.Write("Sum : ");
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Sum());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero is considered and even number.

The code can be simplified.

```
public static void EvenWholeNumber()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int numberOfEvenNumbers = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfEvenNumbers; i += 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        sum += i; ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, 0 is a natural number as defined by ISO-80000-2.  So is 102.  But the OP clearly stated *between 1 and 100*.